# Convert UserName to WindowsIdentity?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, admin, user-accounts

**I've tagged this question with `C#` because is part of `.NET` and is known that some people can programming and understand without problems both `VB.NET` and `C#` as one, and I should not have problems to translate the `C#` instructions to `VB.NET` then I would be happy with a solution written in one of those languages.**

---

I would like to specify an username in this function to retrieve if it's an Admin or not, what changes I should do?

```
MsgBox(UserIsAdmin("Elektro"))

' ByVal UserName as String or other needed object.
Public Function UserIsAdmin(ByVal UserName As XXXX) As Boolean 

    Dim Identity As Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity =
    Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.FromUserName(UserName)

    Return New Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(Identity).
               IsInRole(Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)

End Function
```

PS: Ofcourse the `FromUserName` method does not exist.

---

> UPDATE

I'm just trying @meziantou approach but I always get an exception about the username structure or about the network entry is not found, but, anyways, this is not exactlly what I'm looking for (I mean specify a domain or computername or whatever else that is not done automated by the function).

```
Public Class Form

Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

    ' Things that I've tried:

    MsgBox(UserIsAdmin("Administrador")) ' Username
    MsgBox(UserIsAdmin("Administrador@127.0.0.1")) ' Username@LocalHost
    MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)) ' DomainName\Username
    MsgBox(UserIsAdmin("Administrador@ELEKTRO")) ' Username@DomainName
    MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.User.Value)) ' The SID

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Determines whether an user is an Administrator.
''' </summary>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if the user is an Administrator, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
Public Function UserIsAdmin(Optional ByVal UserName As String = String.Empty) As Boolean

    Dim Identity As Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity =
        If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName),
           New Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(UserName),
           Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())

    Return New Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(Identity).
               IsInRole(Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)

End Function

End Class
```

---

> UPDATE 2

I'm trying the @Frinavale approach but I'm not able to adapt this code to retrieve the information that I'm interested to.

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        Dim pContext As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)
        Dim pUsers As Principal = New UserPrincipal(pContext)
        Dim pSearcher As PrincipalSearcher = New PrincipalSearcher(pUsers)

        For Each User As Principal In pSearcher.FindAll()

            For Each Group As Principal In User.GetGroups
                ' Result of 'Administrators' (in Spanish): 'Administradores', 
                ' so this is not efficient to compare.
                MsgBox(Group.Name)
            Next

            ' Any of these works:
            ' It throws an exception because 
            ' i'm not passing the expected parameter for a WindowsIdentity.

            MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(User.Name))
            ' MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(User.UserPrincipalName))
            ' MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(User.DistinguishedName))
            ' MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(User.SamAccountName))

        Next User

    End Sub

    Public Function UserIsAdmin(ByVal User As String) As Boolean

        Using Identity As New WindowsIdentity(User)
            Return New WindowsPrincipal(Identity).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
        End Using

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: You should consider using the PrincipalSearcher to retrieve a collection of all the principal objects (using the PrincipalSearcher.FindAll) and from there determine which Principal has the identity that you are looking for. 


(PrincipalSearcher info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (FindAll info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.findall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Frinavale Thanks but I can't find the way to adapt it.  I've tried to pass the name that gives me the searcher to the function, but still saying that the name is not correct. so I've tried to check directlly in the searcher whether the user is an Administrator, getting the groups `GetGroups` method, but what I see is that the name of the `Administrators` group is Language dependant, so in my language is totally different name then comparing the name is not efficient. what can I do? please see my updated question if you would. thankyou

Comment: There has to be a way around this localization problem. The "IsInRole" method takes a string, so instead of using the WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator try passing in "Administrator" (of course I'm assuming that the "Administrator" is stored in English...if it isn't, than you will have to use resources to properly localize the word so that it matches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GroupPrincipal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve all users that are part of the administrator group. Once you have all the members, you can determine if the user is in the group by comparing the member's name to the user name provided.

For example:

```
Public Function UserIsAdmin(ByVal userName As String) As Boolean
        Dim groupName As String = "administrators" '<--You can localize this'
        Dim isAdmin As Boolean
        Using context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)
            Dim gfilter As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName)
            If gfilter IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim members = gfilter.GetMembers
                For Each member In members
                    If String.Compare(member.Name, userName, True) = 0 Then
                        isAdmin = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End Using
        Return isAdmin
End Function
```

I know that you mentioned that the group's name is localized (which hasn't occurred for me because I'm using an US English operating system/environment). In that case I recommend that you look into the topic of [Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c08a467e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (store store a localized version of "administrators" into resource files with the key being "administrators" and then retrieve the appropriate text for "administrator" based on the culture that you are working in)

Comment: I don't understand how to localize the properlly name of the Administrators group, the MSDN url does not appears to have info about my problem, could you give an example please? I need this 'UserIsAdmin' to work as universal solution.

Comment: Before we start on the large topic of globalization..Did the above function work for you? If it didn't, did you try setting `groupName = "Administradors"`? Did that work? The above code works for me but I am using US-English culture on a Windows 7 operating system and it sounds like you are using a Spanish culture on your system which is translating "Administrators" into "Administradors" and that you need to compensate for this.

Comment: no, your code should work only with us language ("Administrators"), anyways, following your suggestions about the usage of `Principal` and `GroupPrincipal` and doing more researchs I've found another way, just comparing the SID of the group,  I mean the administrators group SID, I've answered this question with the solution that I've written if someone is interested. thanks for help.

Comment: That is a great idea! Don't know why I didn't think of that :) It gets around any mismatching of group names! Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

To get a `WindowsIdentity` from a user name, you can use the `WindowsIdentity` constructor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td3046fc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim windowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity("administrator")
New WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

Comment: thanks but it throws an exception in my case, it says that the provided name is not an account name with the properlly structure,so I've also tried to specify the domain like `UserIsAdmin("MyPCName\MyUserName")` but stills throwing the exception but anyways if the exception is thrown because that what I would like to do is just specify only the username and not the domain name on the method parametter.

Comment: The constructor indicates that the overload expects an `User Principal Name` (UPN) String, not only an username, I will clarify that my intention is just to pass an username to the method so the domain should be resolved by the method, anyways I'm trying to pass an UPN string without success (It's my first time trying this): `UserIsAdmin("Administrador@127.0.0.1")`

Comment: This example works on my machine, maybe because my machine is a member of a domain

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says that a `WindowsIdentity` object can be only a logged user, so seems impossible to do the username conversion that I wanted, but, this is a working solution:

```
' User Is Admin?
'
' Instructions:
' 1. Add a reference to 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement'.
' 2. Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
'
' Example Usages:
' MsgBox(UserIsAdmin("Administrador"))
' MsgBox(UserIsAdmin(New Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-21-250596608-219436059-1115792336-500")))
'
''' <summary>
''' Determines whether an User is an Administrator, in the current machine.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="UserName">Indicates the account Username.</param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if user is an Administrator, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
Public Function UserIsAdmin(ByVal UserName As String) As Boolean

    Dim AdminGroupSID As New SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")

    Dim pContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)
    Dim pUser As New UserPrincipal(pContext)
    Dim pSearcher As New PrincipalSearcher(pUser)

    Dim User As Principal =
        (From u As Principal In pSearcher.FindAll
        Where u.Name.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault

    If User Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("User with name '{0}' not found.", UserName))
    End If

    Dim IsAdmin As Boolean =
        (From Group As GroupPrincipal In User.GetGroups
         Where Group.Sid = AdminGroupSID).Any

    pContext.Dispose()
    pSearcher.Dispose()
    pUser.Dispose()

    Return IsAdmin

End Function
```